# Why post-receive's bash doesn't work?

Tags: git

I have a co-working project among several clients and deployed on a server.

### server side

1. create a remote repo `s1` with `git init --bare` at `/root/s1`and clone `s1` to `/root/s2`with `git clone`.
2. add a bash script in `s1`'s `post-receive` hook:`cd /root/s2 && git pull`

### client side

all clients clone `s1`, so they can push changes to `s1`.

However, every time I push any changes to `s1`, `s2` won't sync. If I manually type `cd /root/s2 && git pull` in the server side, it works. So what's the problem?

Update:
I append `echo "xxx">>here` to `post-receive` and after pushing there is a `here` file appears. this proves the bash is correctly executed.

Comment: Does the remote echo any error messages?

Comment: @weeniearms it's `remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this into your `post-receive` hook instead:

```
git --git-dir=/root/s2/.git --work-tree=/root/s2 pull
```

Comment: It worked. thx. It seems that `git` command in `post-receive` is not executed independently.